# Error when trying to bring up the test-network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I trying to follow tutorials and develope on MacOS ,When I want to run the next command to bring up the network`./network.sh up`,[the error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbBiC.png),but my env variable is set and have binaries and crypto folders.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37Qej.png),I don't know how to solve this problem, please help!

Answer (score 0):

When peer binaries and config files are not found, it means that you need to set the path to locate the Hyperledger bin folder and point a fabric config environment variable to the config folder.

I tend to keep the bin and config up one level from the Hyperledger network code and have environment variables start off as the following

```
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD/../config/
export PATH=${PWD}/../bin:$PATH
export IMAGE_TAG="latest"
export COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME="net"
export CC_PACKAGE_VERSION=1
export CC_PACKAGE_SEQUENCE=1
```